# error when trying to declare a vector in private on a header file

Tags: c++, vector, header

Hey i was advised to declare my vector in private(Iventory.h) instead of having in globally in the .cpp(Inventory.cpp) which i had done.  But now there are a lot of errors spitting out at me.

Here are the **errors**:

```
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'  c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.h   22  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.h   22  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   3   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'  c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.h   22  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   4   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'  c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.h   23  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   5   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.h   23  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   6   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'  c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.h   23  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   7   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'  c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.h   24  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   8   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.h   24  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   9   error C2039: 'const_iterator' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.h   24  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   10  error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'  c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.h   24  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   11  error C2065: 'inventory' : undeclared identifier    c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.cpp 18  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   12  error C2228: left of '.push_back' must have class/struct/union  c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.cpp 18  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   13  error C2065: 'inventory' : undeclared identifier    c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.cpp 39  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   14  error C2228: left of '.size' must have class/struct/union   c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.cpp 39  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   15  error C2065: 'inventory' : undeclared identifier    c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.cpp 42  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   16  error C2228: left of '.size' must have class/struct/union   c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.cpp 42  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   17  error C2065: 'inventory' : undeclared identifier    c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.cpp 43  1   MaroonedCA2
```

**Inventory.h**

```
#ifndef INVENTORY_H
#define INVENTORY_H
#include <string>

using namespace std; 
class Inventory
{
public:
    //Constructor
    Inventory();

    //Methods.
    string add(string item);
    void displayInventory();
    void showInventory();
private:
    //Data members
   vector<string> inventory;
   vector<string>::iterator myIterator;
   vector<string>::const_iterator iter;
    };


#endif //INVENTORY_H
```

**Inventory.cpp**

```
#include "Inventory.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>   //  To enable the use of the vector class.
#include <string>


using namespace std;



Inventory::Inventory()
{

}

string Inventory :: add(string item)
{
inventory.push_back(item);
return item;
}

void Inventory:: showInventory()
{
char input[80];
    cin >> input;
    char inventoryRequest[] = "i";
    int invent = strcmp (input,inventoryRequest);
    //compare the player input to inventoryRequest (i) to see if they want to look at inventory.
    if(invent == 0)
    {
        displayInventory();
    }


}
void Inventory:: displayInventory()
{
//vector<string> inventory;
    cout<< "You have " << inventory.size() << " items.\n";
    cout << "\n******Inventory******";
    cout<< "\nYour items:\n";
    for (int i= 0; i< inventory.size(); ++i)
        cout<< inventory[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: `Inventory.h` needs to include `#include<vector>`, Also `using namespace std;` in a header is a bad practice.

Comment: A lot of people here saying `using namespace std;` is bad practice, but not saying why. You might want to read [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/using-namespace-std.html), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include `<vector>` in your `Inventory.h` file.

This is not related to the error, but you should also avoid putting `using namespace std` in header files. `using namespace` negates the advantages of having namespaces, and by putting it in the header, you force it upon any code that includes your header. This could break code in mysterious ways. Personally, I would not use `using namespace std` anywhere. The potential for disorder far outweighs the (quite modest) benefits.

Comment: Grand thanks.  That was poor common sense on my part.  Thanks for helping me with that.

Answer (score 2):

you need to `#include <vector>` in header file

```
#ifndef INVENTORY_H
#define INVENTORY_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>

//using namespace std;   <-- get rid of this line
//it's bad idea to include all std stuff into your code
class Inventory
{
public:
  //Constructor
  Inventory();

  //Methods.
  std::string add(std::string item);
  void displayInventory();
  void showInventory();
private:
  //Data members
  std::vector<std::string> inventory;          
//^^^  use full namespace qualified variables
  std::vector<std::string>::iterator myIterator;
  std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter;
};


#endif //INVENTORY_H
```

in Inventory.cpp, also provide namespace for string

```
std::string Inventory :: add(std::string item)
{
  inventory.push_back(item);
  return item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make long things short:

Write

```
#include <vector>
```

into your .h file and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include

```
#include <vector>
```

in your header file. Also doing `using namespace std` in header files is poor practice.